# New to pine script, I have a question on linking conditions

Tags: pine-script

I am new to Pine script. Have been using FX dreema. but want to move to trading view.

Want to write an alert for when the EMA's are in correct order than a pullback occurs to an EMA. But unsure on how to link the 2 conditions.

not finding reference manual easy to follow

```
//@version=1
study(title="MA Cross ATTEMPT", overlay=true)

    s20ema = ema(close, 20)
    s50ema = ema(close, 50)
    s80ema = ema(close, 80)


    plot(s20ema, title="Ema 20", color = yellow, linewidth = 1, transp=0)
    plot(s50ema, title="Ema 50", color = red, linewidth = 1, transp=0)
    plot(s80ema, title="Ema 80", color = white, linewidth = 2, transp=0)


    longCond = crossover(s20ema, s50ema) and (s20ema > s80ema) and (s50ema > s80ema)
    shortCond = crossunder(s20ema, s50ema) and (s20ema < s80ema) and (s50ema < s80ema)

    buy_pullback = open > s20ema and low < s20ema
    sell_pullback = open < s20ema and low > s20ema

    alertcondition(buy_pullback, title='Long', message='EURAUD_buy')
    alertcondition(sell_pullback, title='Short', message='EURAUD_sell')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to learn Pine v4, which is the current version, so this code uses v4 (see first line). Your code is modified so that it keeps track of two different states: `longCond` and `shortCond`, and the chart's background reflects those. When in state `longCond`, `buy_pullback` can occur. When in state `shortCond`, `sell_pullback` can occur. I changed the `low` for a `high` in your `sell_pullback` condition. Comments in code explain what's going on. Not sure this is what you needed, but it may help you get on your way.

```
//@version=4
study(title="MA Cross ATTEMPT", overlay=true)

s20ema = ema(close, 20)
s50ema = ema(close, 50)
s80ema = ema(close, 80)

plot(s20ema, title="Ema 20", color = color.yellow, linewidth = 1, transp=0)
plot(s50ema, title="Ema 50", color = color.red, linewidth = 1, transp=0)
plot(s80ema, title="Ema 80", color = color.white, linewidth = 2, transp=0)

// ————— This switches between long and short conditions.
// The declarations with "var" allow the variable's value to be preserved throughout bars.
var longCond = false
var shortCond = false
if not longCond and crossover(s20ema, s50ema) and (s20ema > s80ema) and (s50ema > s80ema)
    // These ":=" assignment operators are required because we are changing the value of previously declared variables.
    // If we used "=" here, we would be declaring new variables local to each "if" block that would disappear once out of it.
    longCond := true
    shortCond := false
if not shortCond and crossunder(s20ema, s50ema) and (s20ema < s80ema) and (s50ema < s80ema)
    shortCond := true
    longCond := false
// This colors the background to show which state you are in.
bgcolor(longCond ? color.green : shortCond ? color.red : na, transp = 85)

// The entry triggers only occur when we are in the proper state.
buy_pullback = longCond and crossover(open, s20ema) and low < s20ema
sell_pullback = shortCond and crossunder(open, s20ema) and high > s20ema

// These plot when your entries occur, so that you can verify where they trigger.
plotchar(buy_pullback, "buy_pullback", "▲", location.belowbar, color.lime, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(sell_pullback, "sell_pullback", "▼", location.abovebar, color.fuchsia, size = size.tiny)

alertcondition(buy_pullback, title='Long', message='EURAUD_buy')
alertcondition(sell_pullback, title='Short', message='EURAUD_sell')
```

[image]